# How to display the second last object from DB in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model for news. It looks like:

```
class Post (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='news_image', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

`views.py` looks like:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'html/main.html'


class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'html/post_detail.html'
```

Each news has it's own url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='main'),
    path('news/<int:pk>/', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='news_page')]
```

I use django admin to add posts.
On `main.html` I want to display title and image of the **second last post** from database. I also need a link to that post.

```
<img src="?????" href="????">
<p>{{ ??? }}</p>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

That is not something you do in the template. Instead, add it to the context in your view by defining `get_context_data`.

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'html/main.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['second_last_post'] = Post.objects.all().reverse()[1]
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

(Note, since you don't define any ordering, what consists of the "second last post" is fairly arbitrary.)

Comment: I do not understand what will be there in `main.html`

Comment: `{{ second_last_post.image.url }}`, for example.

Comment: Er, no, a post is a single thing, why would you iterate it?

Comment: No, it returns an a Post instance.

Comment: Not true. I am indexing the queryset, which gives an instance.

Comment: Can it have negative indexing?